# Customise JSON decoder for nested object with Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoding, decoder

Using Swift for iOS 13+, I need to decode a JSON response. It contains a nested object which needs a value (`type`) of the parent object for it decoding.

The JSON structure:

```
{
    "name":"My email",
    "type":"Email",
    "content":{
        "issued":"2023-08-25T12:58:39Z",
        "attributes":{
            "email":"mail@mail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "name":"My telephone",
    "type":"Telephone",
    "content":{
        "issued":"2023-08-25T12:58:39Z",
        "attributes":{
            "telephone":"+33123456789"
        }
    }
}
```

`attributes` content depends of `type`. So `content` nested object needs to know `type` to be able to decode `attributes`.

The structures:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let content: ContentResponse?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        // !!! Here I need to pass the "type" value to content decoding
        content = try container.decodeIfPresent(ContentResponse.self, forKey: .content)
    }
}

struct ContentResponse: Decodable {
    let issued: Date
    let attributes: AttributesResponse?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        issued = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .issued)
        if container.contains(.attributes) {
            // !!! Here I can't access the "type" value from parent object
            switch Type.fromString(type: type) {
            case .telephone:
                attributes = try container.decode(AttributesTelephoneResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
            case .email:
                attributes = try container.decode(AttributesEmailResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
            default:
                // Unsupported type 
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .attributes, in: contentContainer, debugDescription: "Type \"\(type)\" not supported for attributes")
            }
        } else {
            attributes = nil
        }
    }
}

class DocumentResponse: Decodable {}

class AttributesEmailResponse: DocumentResponse {
    let email: String
}

class AttributesTelephoneResponse: DocumentResponse {
    let telephone: String
}
```

As you can see, `init(from decoder: Decoder)` of `ContentResponse` needs to know the `type` to be able to know which class to use for `attributes` decoding.

How can I pass the `type` decoded on `Response` to the nested object `ContentResponse` for it decoding?

## NOT WORKING #1

I found maybe a solution here https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/the-mysterious-codablewithconfiguration-protocol/ using `CodableWithConfiguration` with `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:configuration:)`, but it targets iOS 15+ while I target iOS 13+.

## NOT WORKING #2

I could have used `userInfo` of `decoder` in `init(from decoder: Decoder)` to pass `type`, but it's read-only:

```
var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] { get }
```

## SOLUTION

Thanks to @Joakim Danielson for the answer.

The solution is to do the whole decoding in `Response`:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let content: ContentResponse?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case type
        case content
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        // Content
        if container.contains(.content) {
            let issued = try contentContainer.decode(Date.self, forKey: .issued)
            let attributes: DocumentResponse?
            switch DocumentType.fromString(type: type) {
            case .telephone:
                let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentTelephoneResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
                attributes = .telephone(value)
            case .email:
                let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentEmailResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
                attributes = .email(value)
            default:
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .attributes, in: contentContainer, debugDescription: "Type \"\(type)\" not supported for attributes")
            }
            content = ContentResponse(issued: issued, expires: expires, attributes: attributes, controls: controls)
        } else {
            content = nil
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
public enum DocumentType: String, Codable {
    case telephone = "Telephone"
    case email = "Email"

    static public func fromString(type: String) -> Type? {
        Type(rawValue: type) ?? nil
    }
}

struct ContentResponse: Decodable {
    let issued: Date
    let attributes: DocumentResponse?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case issued
        case attributes
    }
}

enum DocumentResponse: Decodable {
    case email(DocumentEmailResponse)
    case telephone(DocumentTelephoneResponse)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use enums for this, one for the type of content and one to hold the decoded content.

First the enum for the `type`

```
enum ContentType: String, Codable {
    case email = "Email"
    case phone = "PhoneNumber"
    case none
}
```

And then the one for `content`

```
enum Content: Codable {
    case email(DocumentEmailResponse)
    case phone(DocumentPhoneNumberResponse)
    case none
}
```

I changed the types used in `Content` to be structures

```
struct DocumentEmailResponse: Codable {
    let email: String
}

struct DocumentPhoneNumberResponse: Codable {
    let phoneNumber: String
}
```

Then all custom decoding takes part in `Response` where the `Content` values is decoded using a nested container.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let name: String
    let type: ContentType
    let content: Content

    enum ContentCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case attributes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        type = try container.decode(ContentType.self, forKey: .type)
        let contentContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ContentCodingKeys.self, forKey: .content)
        switch type {
        case .email:
            let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentEmailResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
            content = .email(value)
        case .phone:
            let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentPhoneNumberResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
            content = .phone(value)
        default:
            content = .none
        }
    }
}
```

Both the enumerations contains a `none` case but depending on what might be optional or not and personal preferences you might want to remove them if possible, I wasn't completely sure which and when values can be nil.

---

As noted by @Rob in the comments it might be good to handle unknown types without failing the decoding process. Below is an alternative way to do this and also see the link in the comments for another alternative.

The new custom init for decoding is

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    let contentValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)

    self.type = ContentType(rawValue: contentValue) ?? .none
    let contentContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ContentCodingKeys.self, forKey: .content)
    switch type {
    case .email:
        let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentEmailResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
        content = .email(value)
    case .phone:
        let value = try contentContainer.decode(DocumentPhoneNumberResponse.self, forKey: .attributes)
        content = .phone(value)
    case .none:
        content = .unknownType(contentValue)
    }
}
```

This requires a change to the `Content` enum

```
enum Content: Codable {
    case email(DocumentEmailResponse)
    case phone(DocumentPhoneNumberResponse)
    case unknownType(String)
    //case none <- this might still be relevant if content is optional
}
```

Comment: Good answer (+1). The only thing I might add would be to change `ContentType` so that it doesn’t throw an error if the decoded value is not amongst its enumerated values. I also capture the value of the unknown string (which I find to be helpful in diagnosing issues when the server introduces some unknown key). E.g., https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/696c7409de2da38ee568f53e16154674.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good point. I'll add my solution which is slightly different but based on your suggested idea.